# How to get AC power supply for projects?

Tags: ac

So im planning to do electrical and electronics projects in my upcoming 2 month summer vacation. I bought some books for this (Example Getting started in electronics by Forrest)
But I soon realised that many projects require AC supply to fully implement it and see it effect(clippers, transistor circuit etc). So how can I get AC supply in my home?

Comment: Has your home got electricity? If so, what sort? DC or AC? What voltage?

Comment: @Transistor I have AC supply, but how do you connect it to a breadboard for a simple transistor circuit lets say

Comment: @Transistor I think its a foolish idea to connect 220V AC to a breadboard

Comment: @user29463 not wanting to connect a breadboard to a power outlet is definitely a survival skill! But, with a *transformer*, you can be safe. You can get arbitrary transformers. Just look for the "wall wart" power supplies that say e.g. "out: 9 VAC" or "out: 12 V~". Obviously, you'll need something that produces the voltage your circuit needs, and is able to supply at least the current that it'll draw – but for small things like transistor circuits, it'll be impossible to find transformers that are "too weak".

Comment: You could look for a function generator or build one yourself using a microcontroller like [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-DIY-waveform-generator-analog-devices-ad9833-ATmega328p/). I have mostly used function generator in our analog electronics lab for getting AC supply to test circuits, and also sometimes used a 220V : 12V transformer for that purpose.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Using a wall wart makes more practical to me. Any tutorial/video on how to use a wall wart as a AC source?

Comment: It's transformers, not just any wall wart. It **is** an AC source when it says "VAC" or "V~" on the thing! There's nothing you need to "do" to use it as such.

Comment: how to use a wall wart as a AC source?  The output is usually a barrel type connector. Cut it off and strip the leads, or buy the mating connector.

Comment: If you can't find an AC wall wart, some toy train transformers have AC output. You could also use a door bell transformer or low-voltage outside lighting transformer, but you would need to attach a wall cord.